# How may I manually sort Jekyll pages using yaml?

Tags: jekyll

I'm converting an old site from a PHP CMS to Jekyll, and I'd like to retain the manually ordered pages. Initially, I thought I could rename the files to contain the index, e.g. `01-start-here.markdown`, `02-learn-more.markdown` etc. This would make things awkward if I ever added a page further down the line.

Ideally I'd like to specify a `yaml` file containing the page order. For example:

```
category: basics
pages:
  - start here
  - learn more
  - overview

category: advanced
pages:
  - diving further
  - wrapping up
```

Is this possible? Looking at the [Jekyll site](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/tree/master/site) they seem to have a manually ordered site, but I can't quite figure out how.

Additionally, to further compound the issue, I'd like this to be assigned to `pages` so `page.next` would automatically move to the `advanced` category after the last page of `basics` category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jekyll documentation code

**_data/docs.yml**

```
- title: chapter 1
  docs:
  - home
  - page
  - other

- title: Other chapter
  docs:
  - toto
  - etc
```

In Jekyll, documentation is contained in a **_docs** collection but this can be easily adapted to works with pages.

Navigation in in **_includes/docs_contents.html**

```
<div class="unit one-fifth hide-on-mobiles">
  <aside>
    {% for section in site.data.docs %}
    <h4>{{ section.title }}</h4>
    {% include docs_ul.html items=section.docs %}
    {% endfor %}
  </aside>
</div>
```

**_includes/docs_ul.html**

```
{% assign items = include.items %}
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
  {% assign item_url = item | prepend:"/docs/" | append:"/" %}
  {% if item_url == page.url %}
    {% assign c = "current" %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign c = "" %}
  {% endif %}
  {% for p in site.docs %}
    {% if p.url == item_url %}
      <li class="{{ c }}"><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
      {% break %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The footer prev/next navigation is in **_includes/section_nav.html**

```
{% comment %}
Map grabs the doc sections, giving us an array of arrays. Join, flattens all
the items to a comma delimited string. Split turns it into an array again.
{% endcomment %}
{% assign docs = site.data.docs | map: 'docs' | join: ',' | split: ',' %}

{% comment %}
Because this is built for every page, lets find where we are in the ordered
document list by comparing url strings. Then if there's something previous or
next, lets build a link to it.
{% endcomment %}

{% for document in docs %}
  {% assign document_url = document | prepend:"/docs/" | append:"/" %}
  {% if document_url == page.url %}
    <div class="section-nav">
      <div class="left align-right">
          {% if forloop.first %}
            <span class="prev disabled">Back</span>
          {% else %}
            {% assign previous = forloop.index0 | minus: 1 %}
            {% assign previous_page = docs[previous] | prepend:"/docs/" | append:"/" %}
            <a href="{{ previous_page }}" class="prev">Back</a>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="right align-left">
          {% if forloop.last %}
            <span class="next disabled">Next</span>
          {% else %}
            {% assign next = forloop.index0 | plus: 1 %}
            {% assign next_page = docs[next] | prepend:"/docs/" | append:"/" %}
            <a href="{{ next_page }}" class="next">Next</a>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a really excellent, verbose answer. Thank you so much.